# Does sendmsg system call validate IPv6 source-address added into ancillary data?

Tags: linux, network-programming

I see following behavior with sendmsg in case of IPv4:

Suppose that 10.1.2.3 is the client IP.
And 10.1.2.10 is configured on one of the interfaces of client.

In an UDP message, following control information is added into the packet:

It is just the source-address or interface address that server should use in replying back to the client:

```
cmsg->cmsg_len = sizeof(struct cmsghdr) + sizeof(sa->sin_addr);
cmsg->cmsg_level = IPPROTO_IP;
cmsg->cmsg_type = IP_SENDSRCADDR_WITH_ERROR;
* (struct in_addr *)CMSG_DATA(cmsg) = sa->sin_addr;
cmsg = (struct cmsghdr *)((caddr_t) cmsg + ALIGN(cmsg->cmsg_len));
```

And message is sent as:

```
sendmsg(fd, send_msg, 0);
```

If I configure 10.1.2.10 as source-ip and once it is added into cmsg, things work fine.
server replies back to 10.1.2.10.

But, if I configure some un-reachable IP address or IP that is not configured on any interface on the client, sendmsg fails with below error:

> sendmsg to 10.1.2.3(10.1.2.3).1813 failed: Can't assign
>   requested address

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

But I do not see the same behavior with IPv6:

Suppose that 2001::1 is the client IP.
And 2001::2001 is configured on one of the interfaces of client.

IPv6 source address is added into control message as below:

```
    cmsg->cmsg_level = IPPROTO_IPV6;
    cmsg->cmsg_type = IPV6_PKTINFO;
    cmsg->cmsg_len =  CMSG_LEN(sizeof(struct in6_pktinfo));
    memcpy((struct in6_addr *)CMSG_DATA(cmsg), &(sa6->sin6_addr),
            sizeof(sa6->sin6_addr));
    cmsg = (struct cmsghdr *)((caddr_t) cmsg + ALIGN(cmsg->cmsg_len));
```

It works fine, if I configure 2001::2001 as source-ip and server does reply back to this address.

But If I configure an unreachable IPv6 source address say 1001::1001, there is no error message from sendmsg similar to the one we see in IPv4 case. Message is still sent with original IPv6 which is 2001::1.

Can someone please suggest on what can be the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

IP_SENDSRCADDR and IPV6_PKTINFO must be two different implementations. Maybe in the first case it just control errors. Have you tried to set the interface index in the ancillary data for IPV6_PKTINFO? For IPV6_PKTINFO the ancillary data is of type: in6_pktinfo.

```
struct in6_pktinfo {
    struct in6_addr ipi6_addr;    /* src/dst IPv6 address */
    unsigned int    ipi6_ifindex; /* send/recv if index */
};
```

Hope this helps in some way

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same issue, I set source address as `408:6666:f:f500::1` **(not local IP)**, but I received the packet with `4085:6666:f:fc10::1` **(the local IP)** as source address, no matter I set `ipi6_ifindex` or not.

I will get forward to investigate it.